# is it possible to add custom logic in zookeeper server which can act as path watcher?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

in my application i need some action to be taken even if no zk client node remains which can handle the path watcher notifications.

so i want to add custom logic to zookeeper server which will act as the path watcher and do some action based on it.

I have seen example where authentication logic can be added as a plugin to the zookeeper server. same way i want to add a custom plugin to act as path watcher for ephemeral nodes.

is it possible to add custom logic in zookeeper server which can act as path watcher?

Comment: Are you sure this is the best approach?  What about having each client register an ephemeral node?  Then you can monitor the ephemeral nodes and when none remain then you know no clients remain and can take action?

Comment: that is the point, if no clients remain, then no one can take action. i need to have a separate node just for this extreme case